# The ported Node.js to QNX OS, is it accessible somewhere?

Tags: node.js, qnx

I have read on [QNX blog](http://qnxauto.blogspot.de/2012/12/meet-qnx-concept-team-allan-hudgins-web.html) that **Node.js is ported to QNX OS**, but I cannot find any more details in this regard. I tried to contact the mentioned person on that post, but received no reply yet. I also asked the same question on QNX Foundry27 forums, waiting for an answer.

Does anyone know if the ported Node.js to QNX OS is accessible somewhere?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have received the ported source code.

And here it is shared with you : http://blog.hemnik.com/2014/06/nodejs-for-qnx-source-code.html !